# Absolute Image URL in srcset is appended to the upload dir

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I've WooZoone, Woocommerce installed and Divi for my theme.
The product detail pages look perfect. But when I add a product block i.e. on my front-page, the images are not shown.

The generated HTML code is:

```
<img width="300" height="300" src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS300_.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS300_.jpg 300w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS150_.jpg 150w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS768_.jpg 768w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS1024_.jpg 1024w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS400_.jpg 400w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS1080_.jpg 1080w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS510_.jpg 510w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS600_.jpg 600w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS100_.jpg 100w, https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/416uQ46gN5L._SS64_.jpg 64w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

All links in the srcset are `https://armbanduhr-angebote.com/wp-content/uploads/` + `absolute amazon url`.

Does anyone know where this is comming from and how I can fix this?

Comment: How are you uploading images to Amazon. Are you using a plugin for that? Whichever plugin that is appears to be responsible for the issue. I suggest sending them a support request.

Comment: WooZoone is getting the images and setting the paths. I am just wondering, why the `src` is correct and only the `srcset` is wrong. It's also only happening on product overviews but not on a product detail page. That's why I guess, that's not a problem with the plugin itself.

Comment: Well it certainly sounds like an issue with the plugin to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you worked around that issue - still I stumbled over your post having the same issue. I was able to work around by applying a bugfix from woozone itself - in your wordpress solution with woozone enabled go to:

1. WZone -> Config -> Bug Fixes
2. Scroll down to the option  "Disable WordPress Images Srcset attributes"
3. Set the option value to Yes
4. Save the settings.

The issue was in my case that if multiple images were present, an woozone applied medias stored on amazon (my setting was on no but the plugin still does it in certain cases) the srcset was generated with the sites image upload url, followed with the absolute amazon url, as you described.

Comment: No, I was not able to solve it, but also don't work currently with it. Thank you for your follow-up and the solution. Will try it, when it happens somewhere again